# C# ClosedXML Performance on applying conditional formatting to a large group of cells

Tags: c#, .net, excel, closedxml

```
        var valuesC = this.Charges.Where(x => x.Type == PropertyType.Charge).ToList();
        foreach(var valueCharge in valuesC)
        {
            var column = Sheet.Column(valueCharge.Id);
            foreach(var cell in column.Cells())
            {
                cell.AddConditionalFormat().WhenIsTrue($"ISNUMBER(${cell.Address})=FALSE").Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.Red);
            }
        }
```

This operation being performed on about 30 columns is extremely slow and this is with a small number of rows, is there a way to increase the performance of this code in ClosedXML? It takes about 2-3 minutes on 12 rows. Is there something I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply conditional formatting on a cell by cell basis, but on the largest range possible. Basically, do it like you would do it in Excel, which is probably selecting the whole column and applying the conditional formatting once per column.

Comment: How would the same desired effect be achieved as the code above?